# Importing xls sheet with custom source file

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Im trying to create a vba importing sheet from a different xls. I want the user of main xlsm to have access to change the location for the import file from a cell.(not editing the vba)

I used the macro recorder to get this file and there is something in this code that is not working. I guess its something here: `(File.Contents( import_path ), null, true)`

```
    'Source importfile
    import_path = Sheets("dagsbud").Range("q14")

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="page", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Kilde = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents( import_path ), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    page_Sheet = Kilde{[Item=""page"",Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Endret type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(page_Sheet,{{""Column1"", Int64.Type}, {""Column2"", type any}, {""Column3"", type" & _
        " any}, {""Column4"", type any}, {""Column5"", type any}, {""Column6"", type any}, {""Column7"", type any}, {""Column8"", type any}, {""Column9"", type any}, {""Column10"", type any}, {""Column11"", type any}, {""Column12"", type any}, {""Column13"", type any}, {""Column14"", type any}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Endret type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=page;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [page]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "page"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When building up the formula, `import_path` should not fall inside the quotation marks (before `Kilde=...` and after `...true),`). You need to concatenate with `&`.

Comment: `Kilde = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(&import_path), null, true)` Like this? get error on that

Comment: Why use VBA? You can use a named range to capture the filename, then your query can reference that named range - so the user just has to enter the file name, then refresh the existing query.

Comment: @Olly Do you have an example of this? Link or something, Cant find correct words in google.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=power+query+named+range